# Alphabetical order

Tags: c++

i'm reading a book and i got an exercise to do. It says something like :"write in alphabetical order from a to z"in a while loop. I know that i have to start from 97 (a=97) and b=char('a'+1) , c=char('a'+2). Here's the code:

```
int main(){
int a = 97;
while (a<=122)
{
    cout << char('a'+1) << "\t" << 'a' + 1 << "\n";
    ++a;
}
```

Now the problem is that is shows only b and increments on numbers only .. I'm kinda new to this , any help ?

Comment: replace `'a'` with `a` and see what happens.

Comment: what has the title got to do with the question?

Comment: char('a'+1) will always return b. sio change it to char(a+1)

Comment: You can and should use `'a'` and `'z'` instead of `97` and `122`

Comment: Can you please take some time to [edit] the question and make it clearer? The title has nothing to do with the question, as Tim Rutter said, and I'd also add that `It says something like :"write in alphabetical order" blah blah , with a while loop.` isn't really a clear problem statement. We have to look at the code and guess what you want to do. For example, you could say: "I have to use a `while` loop to print all the lowercase letters of the alphabet, from `a` to `z`, and next to each one I also have to write its ASCII code." Also, the code you have provided doesn't compile!

Answer (score 1):

The problem ist that you use quotation marks in : 
`cout << char('a'+1) << "\t" << 'a' + 1 << "\n";`

If you change the line to :

`cout << char(a+1) << "\t" << a + 1 << "\n";`

it should work. 
If you write 'a' you are taking the value of the letter a(which is 97) and not the value of your variable a.